# Project Navigator Files All Missing

Tags: xcode

So I decided to [rename my project](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/RenamingaProject/RenamingaProject.html). After that I proceeded by searching for instances of the app's previous name within my project, and replacing it with the new one.

Now, when I open my `.xcodeproj`, all the references to my files are missing and they're displayed red.

Where can I find the settings for the project root path?

Comment: Did you rename your folder?

Comment: I got the same issue one time. I solved this by remove all missing file (on your xcode, select and choose delete) then add it again to my project.

Answer (score 0):

I think that to rename a project you should use the Xcode Utility ( click on the Project menu and select Rename) :

[image: Rename Project]

In your case make sure that you have renamed the ".xcodeproj" to ".xcodeproj" and then edit ".xcodeproj/project.pbxproj" and replace the "appropriate" occurrences of "" with ""

Take a look at this utility : [Xcode-project-renamer](https://github.com/southdesign/Xcode-Project-Renamer) that should automate the procedure.